# Ist es korrekt, mit der Vorsilbe „nicht“ Adjektive zu bilden?

Tags: adjective, prefix, negation, compound

### Frage

Ist es korrekt, mit der Vorsilbe *nicht* Adjektive zu bilden?

### Beispiel:

Ich möchte das Wort *literarisch* verneinen.
Wenn ich die Vorsilbe *un* verwende, entsteht das Wort *unliterarisch*.
Wenn ich aber von etwas behaupte, es sei unliterarisch, klingt es, als handle es sich dabei um schlechte Literatur:
„Die unliterarischen Beiträge in der Zeitschrift haben mir nicht gefallen.“

Ich möchte aber mit dem Wort ausdrücken, dass ich die Beiträge, die nicht der Gattung *Literatur* zuzuordnen sind, nicht mag: etwa, wenn es in einer Kunstzeitschrift Literatur und Bilder gibt.

Meine Lösung wäre hier, *nicht* als Präfix zu verwenden:
„Die nichtliterarischen Beiträge in der Zeitschrift haben mir nicht gefallen.“

Ist das eine korrekte Anwendung der deutschen Sprachregeln?
Oder sollte man *nichtliterarisch* besser *nicht literarisch* oder *nicht-literarisch* schreiben, oder es anders ausdrücken?

### Recherche:

In einer (unvollständigen) Liste deutscher Präfixe bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Pr%C3%A4fixe) wird die Vorsilbe *un* zur Verneinung von Adjektiven explizit genannt, das Wort *nicht* jedoch nicht. Es wird auf *Halbpräfixe* verwiesen:

> Präfixe, die als eigenständige Wörter verwendbar sind, werden als
>   Halbpräfix bezeichnet.

Außerdem wird in einer ebenfalls quellenlosen Fußnote angemerkt:

> Spontane Wortschöpfungen durch Präfixe und Halbpräfixe begegnen uns
>   täglich in den Medien. Ob sich diese Neologismen dauerhaft etablieren,
>   ist offen. Der deutsche Wortschatz ist deshalb von ständigen
>   Zuwanderungen und Abwanderungen betroffen.

Dann verweist Wikipedia auf [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Halbpr%C3%A4fix), wo eine einzige Bedeutung von *Halbpräfix* angeführt ist:

> Linguistik: grammatisches Morphem, das in seiner Form einem Lexem
>   gleicht, aber nicht die Bedeutung dieses Lexems hat. Es wird wie ein
>   Präfix für die Ableitung verwendet.

Dort wird canoo.net als Quelle genannt, wo allerdings wenig zum *Halbpräfix* steht: Nomen, Neutrum, Link zum DWDS.
Das DWDS kennt *Halbpräfix* aber nicht.
Weiter wird auf das „Lexikon der Sprachwissenschaft“ von Hadumot Bußmann verwiesen.
Dort steht (unter *Präfixoid*) Ähnliches wie bei Wiktionary.
Bei Metzler ebenso, mit dem Zusatz, dass das Konzept heutzutage umstritten sei.

Comment: Einfacher zu verstehen ist jedenfalls eine positive Aussage. Statt zu sagen: "Nicht-Literatur gefällt mir nicht." klingt es doch leichter, wenn man sagt: "Mir gefällt Literatur." Ich würde eine positive Aussage immer vorziehen, auch wenn es manchmal einfacher ist zu negieren.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein: Ich bin auch ein Freund einfacher Formulierungen, aber die beiden Aussagen liegen doch ziemlich weit auseinander:  der erste Satz sagt über das Gefallen von Literatur überhaupt nichts aus.

Comment: @guidot: Wenn Nicht-Literatur alles außer Literatur ist, was bleibt denn dann noch übrig, was gefallen könnte?

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein: Da es kein Naturgesetz gibt, dass jedem irgendetwas gefallen *muss*, könnte der Sprecher Literatur auch ausgesprochen verabscheuen, begierig verschlingen, ihr gleichgültig gegenüberstehen, sie als Brennmaterial schätzen, ....Keine der Möglichkeiten schließt der erste Satz aus, wohl aber der zweite.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein Dein Argument scheint mir ein klassischer Fall für einen logischen Fehlschluss zu sein: Aus *Ich mag Nicht-Literatur nicht* folgt nicht logisch, dass ich Literatur mag. S. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich halte die Bildung von Adjektiven mit dem Präfix (oder Halbpräfix oder Präfixoid) "nicht" für durchaus zulässig, auch wenn solche Wörter in der Praxis selten vorkommen, weil es meistens unkompliziertere (! - nicht etwa "nichtkomplizierte") Lösungen gibt.

In der Praxis ist mir zuletzt häufig

> nichtfinanzielle Indikatoren

begegnet - dies natürlich in Texten aus Mund und/oder Feder von Wirtschaftswissenschaftlern und Betriebswirten, die sich mit dem Messen von Unternehmenserfolg und *performance* beschäftigen. Hier scheint mir das Wort eingebügert. Es kommt natürlich aus dem Englischen, wo man von *non-financial indicators* spricht.

Weiter ist im Bildungsbereich die Rede von formaler und non-formaler Bildung oder eben

> nicht-formaler Bildung

welche fachsprachlich streng unterschieden wird von *informeller Bildung*, auch wenn das Adjektiv-Triplet hier insgesamt doch etwas nichtglücklich zusammensteht, weil der Unterschied zwischen *informell* und *nicht-formal* dem nichteingeweihten Nichtpädagogen in der Regel nichtverständlich bleiben wird.

Da nicht-Bildungen aber vorkommen, sehe ich keinen Grund, warum an anderer Stelle man nicht dem Beispiel folgen sollte. Natürlich nur dort, wo durch Bildung mit dem etwas sperrigen *nicht* ein Wort entsteht, das etwas ausdrückt, was man nicht auch mit herkömmlichen Negationsvorsilben hätte ausdrücken können. Einen Unterschied zwischen *unnötigen* Wörtern und *nichtnötigen* Wörtern sehe ich nämlich nicht.

Dein Beispiel mit

> nichtliterarischen Beiträgen

in einer Kunstzeitschrift scheint mir gut und zulässig, weil *unliterarische* Beiträge ja danach klängen, als stelle man die Qualität der Literatur in Frage, dabei geht es dir ja um die Einordnung als - eben - nicht der Literatur als Gattung zugehörig. Da "un-" in diesem Zusammenhang schon besetzt ist, verwendest du ausweichend "nicht-" und schaffst eine neue Bedeutung. Nicht unklug!

---

**Ein theorieorientierter Nachtrag:**

Weiter drüber nachdenkend kommt mir folgende Frage: Könnte es sein, dass die Vorsilbe "un-" (oder ihre gräkoromanischen Cousinen) in unserem Hirn primär mit der Bedeutung "Gegenteil von" behaftet ist, während "nicht" lediglich das "Fehlen einer Eigenschaft" bezeichnet?

> unamerikanisch

(ein Wort, das zuletzt sehr häufig zu hören ist) bedeutet ja: "das Gegenteil von dem, was wir als positive Eigenschaften des US-amerikanischen Bürgers und Staates postulieren", was eine eindeutig negative Zuschreibung ist (im Sinne derer, die diesen Ausdruck gebrauchen jedenfalls), während

> nichtamerikanisch

nur meint: "bar der Eigenschaft des Amerikanischseins", was zunächst mit keiner Wertung verbunden ist.

Allerdings scheint dieser Bedeutungszusatz (negative Bewertung) in bestimmten Zusammenhängen unsichtbar zu werden:

> unnötig
>
> unzweifelhaft
>
> unsichtbar

denn diese lassen sich synoynm mit "nicht nötig", "nicht zweifelhaft" und "nicht sichtbar" ersetzen.

**Daraus ziehe ich die Theorie:** "un" bedeutet "negativ", sofern der logische Zusammenhang einen Skalenwert unter Null zulässt. Ist dies logisch nicht gegeben, sind "un" und "nicht" synonym.

---

Zweifel habe ich bei

> Er fühlt sich nicht wohl

versus

> Er fühlt sich unwohl

Ist "unwohl" negativer als "nicht wohl"? Ist "nicht wohl" nur "nicht positiv wohl", während "unwohl" gleich "konkret negativ anti-wohl" ist?

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort. Substantivverkettungen (oder Substantiv-Verkettungen) kann man mit oder ohne Bindestrich schreiben, aber nicht mit Leerzeichen („Deppenleerzeichen“). Würdest du das bei Adjektiven auch so sehen? Du hast ein Beispiel mit („nicht-formal“) und eines ohne („nichtfinanziell“) Bindestrich genannt. Könnte man diese Adjektive auch mit Leerzeichen schreiben? edit: Ich habe gerade gesehen, dass Wiktionary auf die Verwendung von „nicht“ in Verbindung mit Adjektiven eingeht: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/nicht. Demnach ist beides möglich.

Comment: Deppenleerzeichen bei Kettensubstantiven sind in der Tat eine ärgerliche **Un**sitte. Bei Adjektiven sehe ich dagegen Interpretationsspielraum. Man könnte ohne deppert auszusehen von "nicht finanziellen Indikatoren" sprechen. Aber Leute, die von sowas sprechen, sprechen so oft davon, dass sie lieber "nicht-finanziell" sagen (oder schreiben), weil das eine schnellere, glattere Aussprache (samt Betonung auf "nicht") nahelegt, während "nicht finanziell" eher eine kleine Sprechpause suggeriert und die Betonug auf "ziell" hätte. Kurz: je eingebürgerter, desto eher ein Bindestrich (oder zusammen).

Comment: Ich würde noch ergänzen, dass solche Wortbildungen häufig eher in wissenschaftlichen oder mathematischen Texten zu finden sind, z. B. »Man darf nur aus nichtnegativen Zahlen die Quadratwurzel ziehen.«

Comment: ... während in **nichtfachsprachlichen** und **nichtwissenschaftlichen** Texten Adjektive mit Präfix "nicht" eher selten sind sind.

Answer (score 7):

Auf http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html kann man sich eine Liste aller deutschen Wörter herunterladen. Ich habe das schon vor einiger Zeit gemacht, die Liste in eine Datenbank eingepflegt, und kann nun darin komfortabel suchen. (Nein, diese Suche ist nicht öffentlich verfügbar.)

Ich habe nach Wörtern gesucht, die mit *»nicht∙«* beginnen, und mit *»∙isch«* enden. Dazu habe ich mir auch die Häufigkeitsklasse ausgeben lassen. (Das häufigste deutsche Wort ist *»der«*, seine Häufigkeit definiert die Klasse 0. Wörter, die halb so häufig sind, gehören zur Klasse 1, ein Viertel der Häufigkeit entspricht Klasse 2, ein Achtel Klasse 3, usw.)

Gefunden habe ich 59 Wörter, die in dieses Schema passen (in Klammer die Häufigkeitsklasse). Hier ist eine kleine Auswahl daraus:

- nichtjüdisch (17)
- nichteuropäisch (19)
- nichtolympisch (19)
- nichttechnisch (19)
- nichtalkoholisch (19)
- nichteuklidisch (20)
- nichtmetallisch (21)
- nichtakademisch (21)
- nichtamerikanisch (21)
- nichteinheimisch (23)
- nichthierarchisch (23)
- **nichtliterarisch** (23) **<== HIER IST DAS GESUCHTE WORT**
- nichtmoslemisch (23)
- nichtrassisch (23)
- nichttheologisch (23)
- nichtlettisch (24)
- nichtparlamentarisch (24)
- nichtkroatisch (25)

Eine andere Suche lieferte z.B. auch »nichterwerbstätig«, »nichtgläubig« »nichtschuldig«, »nichtöffentlich«, »nichtbehindert«, »nichtehelich«, »nichtsesshaft« und viele mehr. Das heißt: Es ist durchaus möglich, an Adjektive das Präfix *»nicht∙«* anzufügen, und es wurde auch schon mehrfach getan.

Wie man sieht, kommt auch das Wort *»nichtliterarisch«* in diesem Korpus vor, und es hat die Häufigkeitsklasse 23. Das heißt, es ist ungefähr gleich häufig wie *»Abnäher«, »Benzinverkäufer«, »Chaostheoretiker«* oder *»Damenschlüpfer«,* die alle ebenfalls zur Frequenzklasse 23 gehören.

(Frequenzklasse 23 bedeutet übrigens: Wenn in einem Text 8 Millionen mal das Wort »der« vorkommt, ist rein statistisch mit ungefähr einem Exemplar des Wortes »nichtliterarisch« zu rechnen.)

Comment: Die Frequenzklasse ergibt sich dann aus "log2((Anzahl('der')/Anzahl(gesuchtesWort))"? Zumindest ist 2^23 passend zu 8 Millionen.

Comment: Das nenn' ich mal eine fundierte Antwort! Wow!

Comment: "eine Liste aller deutschen Wörter" - vermutlich sollte man diese sehr absolut klingende Formulierung irgendwie einschränken.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Die Liste enthält die Grundformen von mehr als 300.000 deutschen Wörtern, enthält aber keine Eigennamen. Sie enthält alle Wörter bis einschließlich der Frequenzklasse 29. Zu dieser Klasse gehören z.B. »Alleinmädchen«, »Beanschriftung«, »Catchweltmeister«, »Diskothekar«, usw. bis »zeisen« und »zwerch«

Comment: Ich finde ja, dass jedes Wort, das mindestens so häufig verwendet wird wie *Damenschlüpfer*, unbedingt eine Berechtigung hat.

Answer (score 2):

Der Duden führt in der Rechtschreibregel *D 60 Punkt 2* (https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/getrennt-und-zusammenschreibung#D60) an, dass "Verbindungen mit **nicht** als erstem Bestandteil getrennt oder zusammengeschrieben werden"

Beispiele:

- nicht öffentliche *oder* nichtöffentliche Sitzungen
- nicht amtliche *oder* nichtamtliche Verlautbarungen

Von einer Schreibung mit Bindestrich wird allerdings nichts erwähnt und ist daher nicht dudenkonform (oder nichtdudenkonform, aber nicht nicht-dudenkonform)